# Range を permit すると ActionController::UnpermittedParameters エラーが上がる

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```ruby
search_date = Time.parse(params[:article][:created_at])
params[:article][:created_at] = search_date..search_date.end_of_day
@articles = Article.where(article_params)

def article_params
  params.fetch(:article, {}).permit(:category_id, :created_at)
end
```

上記の様なコードを書いていますが、以下の様なエラーが出てしまいます。

```
<ActionController::UnpermittedParameters: found unpermitted parameter: created_at>
```

恐らく Range の扱いが特殊なためだと思われるのですが、 Strong Parameters で Range を使用するには、どうすればよろしいでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

そもそも検索条件として`article_params`を使っているのが変ですね。
`article_params`を使うのであればcreateやupdateなど、データを更新する場合だと思います。

このケースであれば、以下のようなコードでよいと思うのですがいかがでしょうか？

```
search_date = Time.parse(params[:article][:created_at])
date_range = search_date..search_date.end_of_day
@articles = Article.where(created_at: date_range)
```

#### 余談：Time.parseメソッドについて

`Time.parse`と`Time.zone.parse`ではタイムゾーンの扱いが微妙に異なります。  
個人的にオススメなのは後者です。

詳しい理由はこちらの記事を参考にしてみてください。

[RubyとRailsにおけるTime, Date, DateTime, TimeWithZoneの違い](http://qiita.com/jnchito/items/cae89ee43c30f5d6fa2c)

#### 余談、もとい脱線？: 検索フォームを便利に作成するgem

なんとなくの予想ですが、この件は検索条件を指定するフォームがあって、そこの入力値から検索を実行しているコードのような気がします。

そして、`= form_for @article, url: article_search_path, method: :get do |f|` のようなコードを書いているんじゃないでしょうか？

もしそうだとしたら、Ransackというgemを使うと結構楽に検索フォームが作れます。

https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack

Ransackの使い方はネットにいろいろ情報が載っています。
たとえばこのページとかが参考になるかもしれません。

- [検索用のgem「ransack」を使ってみる](http://qiita.com/LuckOfWise/items/e020e896e71d47d0c6a4)

Ransackを活用するとそもそもこういった問題が発生しなくなると思います。

全然的外れなアドバイスだったらすいません。
とりあえずご参考までに。

Comment: 今回の場合、検索条件が0~2個あり、whereにはhashを渡さなければならないのではないと思いました。
私も、strong parametersはMass assignment対策のものなのでwhereには必要ないのでは？　と思っていたのですが、
    Article.where(params[:article])
とすると
    ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
とエラーが出てしまうので、やはりstrong parametersを通して許可を出してあげる必要があるのではと思った次第です。

Time.parseに関しては元々DateTime.parseを使っていたのですが、タイムゾーンの関係から求めている値にならず、そちらのサイトを拝見してTime.parseに置き換えさせて頂いておりました。
今後必要に応じてTime.zone.parseへの置き換えも検討させていただきます。

Comment: このアプリケーションの、当アクションでもransackは使用しているのですが、Gemを使うまでもなくシンプルな記法で解決できそうなのと、別の検索に纏わる処理を記載した際、ransackで少し手こずってしまったので、こういった質問させていただきました。ですが思ったよりも根が深そうなので、躊躇わずにransackを使用してしまうのが良いのかもしれませんね。

Answer (score 0):

`actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb`だと515行目あたりに`PERMITTED_SCALAR_TYPES`という許可するクラスの一覧があって`Range`がそこには含まれていないので`Range`を渡すとフィルタで消されてしまってますね。

ところで、Strong paramatersは元々Mass assignment脆弱性対策のために導入されたものです。これを

- コントローラが受け入れるべきパラメータの検証
- コントローラがモデルに渡す際のパラメータの検証

のどちらと解釈するかですが、ニュアンスとしては前者ではないかなと思います。とすると、値を書き換えるのであればまず先に検証してから編集した方が良いのではないですかね。

```
search_params = article_params
search_date = Time.parse(params[:article][:created_at])
search_params[:created_at] = search_date..search_date.end_of_day
@articles = Article.where(search_params)
```

Comment: 確かに、以前はModelで行われていた検証をコントローラに移したわけですから、想定されている用法としては前者の方がふさわしいかもしれません。